# Is it possible to convert this method in to java 8 using streams? If yes how?

Tags: java-8

Suppose i have one method which takes two arrays of double type than takes a local variable 'sum' of double type with init value of zero. After that a for loop iterates from start to end and subtract like this a1[i] - b[i] and save result into another local variable called minus. Than do minus * minus and sum it with the existing value in sum variable and at the end sum.
I am confuse how can i implement this in java 8 using streams. Can anybody help me?

```
public double calculate(double[] a1, double[] b2, int start, int end) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    final double minus = a1[i] - b2[i];
    sum += minus * minus;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return IntStream.range(start, end)
            .mapToDouble(x -> a1[x] - b2[x])
            .map(x -> x * x)
            .sum();
```

Comment: and for returning sum?

Comment: one more question if i apply parallel() it will work fast?

Comment: @David you would need lots of elements, millions probably, but you need to measure. I would not add parallel...

Comment: And if my array is type of NumberVector[] instead of double[] than what will be the java 8 form ?

Comment: @David what is `NumberVector`?

Comment: An interface named NumberVector and implementation of this interface is provided by DoubleVector.class means If array of DoubleVector is giving to the input of this method instead of double[] than what will be the implementation.

Comment: @David am I suppose to guess how that class looks like?

Comment: DoubleVector. class has a field like this 
private final double[] values; and a constructor like this public DoubleVector(double[] values) {
    this.values = values.clone();
  } for cloning values into field.

Comment: @David this changes the problem, so your method would be `public double calculate(DoubleVector[] a1, DoubleVector[] b2, int start, int end) {...}` how would you write that without streams?

Comment: yes, now question changed. public double calculate(DoubleVector[] a1, DoubleVector[] b2, int start, int end) {...} how would you write that with streams

Comment: @David are you serious? I asked you - how would write it without streams? so that I can understand it and help you writing it *with* streams

Comment: sorry for miss understanding. public double calculate(DoubleVector[] a1, DoubleVector[] b2, int start, int end) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    final double minus = a1[i] - b2[i];
    sum += minus * minus;
  }
  return sum;
} every thing is same only input array type is changed.

Comment: @David of course not - plz compile your code before posting in here! `a1[i] - b2[i]` for `DoubleVector`.. how is that suppose to work?

Comment: public double calculate(DoubleVector[] a1, DoubleVector[] b2, int start, int end) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    final double minus = a1.doubleValue(i) - b2.doubleValue(i);
    sum += minus * minus;
  }
  return sum;
} Now Edited

Comment: @David this is my last comment here... `a1.doubleValue(i)...` did you *even try to* compile this?

Comment: yes, it is a complete framework and compiling and running fine

Comment: @David `DoubleVector[] a1` so `a1` is an array. and you are invoking `a1.doubleValue` - a method on an array. how is this suppose to work?

Comment: public double calculate(DoubleVector a1, DoubleVector b2, int start, int end) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    final double minus = a1.doubleValue(i) - b2.doubleValue(i);
    sum += minus * minus;
  }
  return sum;
}

Comment: @David `IntStream.range(start, end)
            .mapToDouble(x -> a1.doubleValue[x] - b2.doubleValue[x])
            .map(x -> x * x)
            .sum();`

Comment: again return statement is missing

Comment: @David see this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: i did. 
IntStream.range(start, end) .mapToDouble(x -> a1.doubleValue(x) - b2.doubleValue(x)) .map(x -> x * x) .sum();

Comment: Here i faced an issue when i put .parallel() after IntStream.range(start, end) it took 20 minutes to execute but when i put .parallel() after mapToDouble(x -> a1.doubleValue[x] - b2.doubleValue[x]) it took 534 minutes too execute the program. i am confused why this happening instead of reducing runtime. Here start to end limit is 0 to 10 and this calculate method is called 45k times.

Comment: @David ask a new question